# Is the function $f(x,y)=\frac{x_1-y_1}{\|x-y\|}$ bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

Consider $\mathbb R^3$ with the cartesian coordinates $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. Let $K$ be compact of $\mathbb R^3$ and consider $f:\mathbb R^3\times K\to \mathbb R$ defined by:
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x_1-y_1}{\|x-y\|}$$
It is clear that $|f|$ is bounded in $(\mathbb R^3-K)\times K$. But... is also $|f|$ bounded in its entire domain $\mathbb R^3\times K$?

Comment: Is your question the following : is $\frac {u_i}{\lVert u\lVert}$ bounded in $0$ ? But I would say it is not defined in $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for any vector $z$,
$$
|z_1|^2 \leq \sum_k |z_k|^2,
$$
so $|z_1|\leq \|z\|$. Therefore, $\frac{|z_1|}{\|z\|} \leq 1$ if $z≠0$. This works in particular with $z=x-y$. As a remark, if you are working with functions defined for each point, then the you have to remove the diagonal set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^3×K:x=y\}$ from the domain.

Comment: What about the comment posted by zwim at the end of the question? That is, what if $x=y$ and $z=0$. How do you deal with $\frac00$ in your answer? The answer would be that the original question is meaningless, since the so-called "entire domain" makes no sense.

Comment: Here is the question as stated by the OP, in case you didn't have a chance to read it, before you posted your answer. "It is clear that $|f|$ is bounded in $(\mathbb R^3-K)\times K$. But... is also $|f|$ bounded in its entire domain $\mathbb R^3\times K$?"

Comment: I didn't claim that there was something that wasn't clear to me. It is just think that neither to OP now you have written what you meant, and you have left the reader to guess what the correct question should be, and what the correct answer should be.

Comment: Yes, as usual in maths, one writes details depending on his level ... I added details to try to cover your interpretation of the OP question.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably $\|\;\|$ is the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

The function $f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=\frac{x_1-y_1}{\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|}$ is not defined in the set $\Delta:=\{(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})\in\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3:\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{y}\}$. On the other hand
$$|x_1-y_1|\leq \|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|$$

Thus
$$
|f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})|\leq1,\qquad \mathbf{x}\neq\mathbf{y}
$$
It is possible to define $f$ along $\Delta$ so that $f$ becomes bounded on $\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3$